# How to tell SPARK scroll bar in TextArea to recalculate?

Tags: textarea, scrollbar, refresh, flex-spark

I have problem with vertical scroll in SPARK text area. I've added simple code in creation complete to insert 200 lines in text area:

```
private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  for (var iind:uint = 1; iind < 200; iind++)
  {
    testTextArea.text += iind.toString() + "\n";
  }
}
```

And when I start application I noticed that the last 10% (approximately) of scroll bar is "a free walk". When scroll is on 90% page is scrolled all the way down, and when I move thumb of the scroll bar in last 10% of scroll bar nothing moves.

This is all until I change text in text area in browser, then scroll bar acts normal.

Thanks

edit: I tried to dispatch event "change", but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, though it doesn't make much sense, at creationComplete block:

```
testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.value =    testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum;
testTextArea.validateNow();
testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.value = 0;
```

Then when you listen:

```
testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, on Change);
```

You can do whatever you want with:

```
if(testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.value >= (testTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum-5))
```

This certainly looks hacky!